# EXE file of a console application doing nothing and abort when pressing any key

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, console-application

I've written a console application that ran and update some records in Dynamics CRM. It worked fine when run it through `bin\Release` folder.  But it abort if I copy the files from release folder and paste on some other some others computer.

Is there anybody who can let me know how can I resolve the problem??

**Here is what I've in event viewr:**

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          11/3/2015 2:13:01 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ****.****.****.****
Description:
Faulting application name: updateAudits.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x563884c0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18933, time stamp: 0x55a6a16f
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000b3dd
Faulting process id: 0x16d8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1162032fc311e
Faulting application path: C:\Users\*****\Desktop\updateAudits\Release\Release\updateAudits.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 7625d31e-8213-11e5-b719-005056b016ab
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-11-03T10:13:01.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>14183</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>***.***.***.***</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>updateAudits.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>563884c0</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7601.18933</Data>
    <Data>55a6a16f</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>000000000000b3dd</Data>
    <Data>16d8</Data>
    <Data>01d1162032fc311e</Data>
    <Data>C:\Users\SIS!SVC-Dynamics\Desktop\updateAudits\Release\Release\updateAudits.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>7625d31e-8213-11e5-b719-005056b016ab</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Check the eventvwr for the logged error while running the application. Most probably executable is unable to load one of the dependent assembly.

Comment: It looks like you may be referencing some assemblies that are not available on other machines. Make sure that you deploy all required non standard .NET framework assemblies to your bin\Release folder - on reference properties set CopyLocal to True to start with.

Comment: I copied the whole folder of Release located at Bin

Comment: If the referenced assembly is available in GAC on your PC then by default Visual Studio won't copy it to the Release folder, so what you need to do is tell VS that the referenced assembly should be copied there even for local machine it's not required.

Comment: can you guide through steps?

Comment: I've updated the question with event logs

Answer (score 0):

Please check the eventlog(Application) in the copied system which will probably enlight on the assembly which was missing.

Comment: Desription is missing in the event log. Is it works when you copy the release directory to some other path/directory in the same development system?

Comment: Is your development environment and the other system is in same platform (i.e x86 or x64)?

Comment: yes, both are x64. and here is another but short description of the event:
Application: updateAudits.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack: at updateAudits.Program.updateAudits(System.String, System.String, System.String) at updateAudits.Program.Main(System.String[])

Comment: Looks like some files which you are using in your code is missing in the copied system.I think you can revisit your code and make sure the files(created by application/some config file) which you are using exist in the other system also.

Comment: there was nothing installed on that system and I think it caused the problem to run my application. I just copy the same folder to some other system that have IIS, VS or even MS Office and it worked for me. Thank you for your help and support

Comment: Might be due to some configuration file which is missing.